# Observer is not being triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Whenever i call one of the `getNotes()` method in my fragment the obsever is not updating the data. It is however updating is if i go from mainfragment to other fragment and back to mainfragment again...

I don't know what is wrong. Here i am new to livedata please help

```
class MainViewModel  @ViewModelInject constructor(
    val repository: NoteRepository
): ViewModel() {
    
     var notes:  LiveData<List<Note>>



    init {
       
        notes= repository.getAllNotes()

    }
    fun getNotes(){
        notes = repository.getAllNotes()
    }
    fun getFavoriteNotes(){
        notes = repository.getAllNotesFavoriteOrder()
    }
    fun searchNotes(searchString:String){
        notes = repository.getAllNotesQueryTitle(searchString)
```

```
mainViewModel.notes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            adapter.setData(it)
        }
```

```
class NoteRepository @Inject constructor (val noteDao: NoteDao) {



    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note){
        noteDao.insertNote(note)
    }

    fun getAllNotes():LiveData<List<Note>>{
        return noteDao.getAllNotes()
    }

    fun getAllNotesFavoriteOrder():LiveData<List<Note>>{
        return noteDao.getAllNotesFavoriteOrder()
    }
    fun getAllNotesQueryTitle(searchString : String) : LiveData<List<Note>> {
        return noteDao.getAllNotesQueryTitle(searchString)
    }
    suspend fun deleteAllNotes(){
        noteDao.deleteAllNotes()
    }
    suspend fun deleteNote(note: Note){
        noteDao.deleteNote(note)
    }
    suspend fun updateNote(note: Note){
        noteDao.updateNote(note)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your NoteRepository class? And can you fix the top two lines to the syntax you're using? The code above is not compileable.

Comment: try again i forgot to remove some testing code, and i edited the repo in

Answer (score 0):

LiveData should be stored in a read-only `val` property. You keep assigning your read-write `var` property to point at other LiveData instances, so you are not updating the LiveData instance that you are initially observing.

You do need to make the property of type `MutableLiveData` so you can actually update it:

```
 val notes = MutableLiveData<List<Note>>()

 init {
    getNotes()
 }
```

The functions in NoteRepository should be returning `List`s, not `LiveData<List>`s.

In your ViewModel, when you retrieve a list from the repo, assign it to the LiveData's `value` property, for example:

```
fun getNotes(){
    notes.value = repository.getAllNotes()
}
```

A safer pattern is to make your MutableLiveData property private, and exposing a public LiveData version of it, so external classes cannot modify it:

```
 private val _notes = MutableLiveData<List<Note>>()
 val notes: LiveData<List<Note>> get() = _notes

 //...

 fun getNotes(){
     _notes.value = repository.getAllNotes()
 }
```

I suggest changing the function names `getNotes()` and `getFavoriteNotes()` to something like `retrieveNotes()`. Function names that start with `get` look like Java beans or the equivalent of Kotlin properties, so those names are misleading because the functions don't return anything.

Comment: Changing Dao to return List instead of LiveData gives me this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Comment: I don't use Room, but your database interactions should probably use `suspend` functions, and your ViewModel functions that call these suspend functions should be wrapped in `viewModelScope.launch { }`.